# How to get an OAuth2 token using UIWebView and NSURLRequest?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, oauth-2.0, nsurlrequest

I am trying to retrieve an access token for the Facebook API using just a `UIWebview` and `NSURLRequest`s. Because I'd also like to do this with Twitter and Google plus I don't want to include the whole SDK of Facebook in my app. All I need is the access token, as I know how to go on from there.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a this small [example](http://itslennysfault.com/get-facebook-access-token-for-graph-api)

Comment: Hello, can you push it to git or somewhere